# Recent Spike in duplicate accounts for How To Questions

Tags: discussion

I have noticed Recently that there has been a spike in duplicate accounts for posting the same question(s) over and over again. what is the Best course of action? How do we let our colleagues know that user(s) are taking advantage of the forum to get their job done.

Some of these content posts include the following title(s) or simiar to:

- How to filter selected value from selectOption list?
- How to redirect a page to previous record with that record id by clicking the backbutton?
- How to map XML response to sObject?
- how to filter the selected record?
- How to filter response as required(collections)?

As some may have noticed:

- these posts usually contain code related to the Namespace LightningEd, which seems related to adobeconnect.
- Usually is a How To question
- The post is usually poorly formatted and the whole of the body is within a code block, as follows:

  Hi all,
               I'm more confusing to redirect a page from actual page to previous page based on that previous page id value

  ```
          I have two pages 1.Webinar_Details vf page 2.MappingLeadPage

          From the webinar details page i'm redirecting to mappingPage by clicking the "Lead Mapping" page.

          after mapping i want to return to the webinar_Details page by clicking the "Previous Page"

          Webinar Details page :
          -----------------------

          <apex:page standardController="Webinar__c" tabstyle="Adobe_Webinars__tab" sidebar="false" extensions="CheckAllUsingJavascriptController,UpdateWebinarsList,WebinarDetailsReport,RedirectPage">

              <apex:form >   
               <apex:pageBlock title="Adobe Connect Integration with Salesforce">
                   <center>
  ```

Once one of these posts has been identified, I usually flag for moderator attention, however, I was wondering what else can be done? is it advisable to leave a comment identifying the post being from a dup account?

Comment: Flagging is helpful. I think this is a moderator issue. I have reached out to the Community team for support and indicated one user I believe to be the primary culprit. I haven't heard back.

Comment: The key identifiers I've noticed on these are the *misspelled* namespace `LightiningEd` and very confused questions about some kind of mapping process using `Map<String, String>` and  the variable name `customsettingValues`.

Comment: This guy is back today with a [new user account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/53550/basha) and more duplicate questions - I went ahead and flagged them.

Comment: Aaaaaaand, it’s gone

Comment: ... and another round: [question 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207454/how-to-open-third-party-application-home-page-from-salesforce), [question 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207816/how-to-maintain-a-update-callrefreshing-page-untill-call-complete), [user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/53611/basha).

Comment: Aaaaand, their gone.

Comment: Today [two](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/53742/chandra) [users](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/53762/chiru) and the [usual](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207877/how-to-avoid-loop-create-multiple-records) [questions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207922/how-to-login-external-website-from-salesforce-visualforce-page).

Comment: [Today's iteration](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/208634/46017). I like how he's started switching languages on his new user names.

Comment: [Another one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/208678/how-to-filter-duplicates-from-response), this time signed with his real name and email!

Comment: Deleted [another one](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/54828/shanker) today.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keep flagging them. I'm trying to stay on top of it, but any assistance watching out for this behavior is appreciated.

Comment: pretty much looks like its a company doing an adobe connect implementation, seems like they are unable to do so without assistance from the forum. they are posting questions non-stop daily in regards to this.